# why $get() function is too late?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to display values from xml to a form. which is an only html page.

for example 
 config.xml have `<xml><name>abc</name>....</xml>`
and html form have `<form><input id="name"></form>`

to do like this, i was tried to take content of config.xml using ajax() or get() functions 
and then parse xml then display those values on html form.

```
$(function () {
    var content;
    $.ajax('config.xml', {
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            content = data;
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

var $inputs = $('#report_form :input');

$inputs.each(function (index) {
    var inputid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(inputid);
    alert(content);
    var xml = content,
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc),
        $title = $xml.find(inputid);
    alert($title.text());
    text = $title.text();
    $('#' + inputid).val(text);
});
```

i have tried with

```
$.get("config.xml", function(data) {
    xml = data;
    alert(xml);//Do stuff with data here
});
```

in the place of $.ajax();
Now my doubt is while executing this $.get()/$.ajax() are running executing after xml parser only.

how i can execute this  $.get()/$.ajax() before xml parsing.

Comment: It is being executed before xml parsing. your xml parsing is happening too early. ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Call the function to parse the xml from the success function.  Or, look at promises (http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: This is how your code is executing: 1: define content var. 2: send ajax request. 3: iterate over inputs and parse xml content. 4: xml content received. As you can see, 3 is happening before 4, which is happening because of the fact ajax is asynchronous. move 3 to inside the ajax callback and it'l happen at the correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place your code in the call back function .. so that it get's executed when the data is retrieved

```
 $.get("config.xml", function(data) {
    // what ever here will be executed after the data has returned 
    xml = data;
    alert(xml);//Do stuff with data here


    $inputs.each(function (index)
    {
        var inputid=$(this).attr('id');alert(inputid);
        alert(content);
        var xml = content,
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find(inputid);
        alert($title.text());
        text=$title.text();
        $('#'+inputid).val(text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax call will not respond directly. But when it does, the code will be executed inside of it's callback function (`success` in your case).

Just as well as a `setTimeout` will run the callback and not pause the code for this moment.

```
setTimeout(function {alert("hello")}, 500);
alert("I will run before timeout!");
```

You will have to place your code inside of the `success` callback. Other code outside of this will be ran before ajax has successfully sent and retrieved the data.

---

```
$.get("config.xml", function(data) {
    $inputs.each(function (index) {
        // The code is now placed inside the callback and will be successfully ran when ajax has completed.
        var inputid = $(this).attr('id');
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        var text = $(xmlDoc).find(inputid).text();
        $('#'+inputid).val(text);
    });
});
```